# DraggableScrollableSheet fit to content

Tags: flutter

Is there a way that a DraggableScrollableSheet with showModalSheet, fit to content, like a ListView, and avoid this drag up gesture if there is no more content?

[image]

Here is an example code:

```
showModalBottomSheet(
        context: context,
        useSafeArea: true,
        builder: (context) => DraggableScrollableSheet(expand: false,
            builder: (context, scrollController) => ListView(
        controller: scrollController,
            children: [
              Text('Hello',),
              Text('Hello',),
            ],
                                                        ),
                                                      ),
    );
```

Comment: try setting `isScrollControlled` to true. 
 more about it here : https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showModalBottomSheet.html